# MS Teams : Initiate actions with messaging extensions still exists?

Tags: messaging, microsoft-teams, manifest.json

According to Microsoft Documentation it is possible to initiate actions with messaging extensions 
see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/messaging-extensions/create-extensions

To do so, the command must specify the "type" parameter with value "action" (MS example below)

```
"composeExtensions": [
    {
    "botId": "......",
    "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
    "commands": [
        {
          "id": "reassignTodo",
          "description": "Reassign a todo item",
          "title": "Create To Do",
          "type": "Action",
          "fetchTask": true
        }
    ]
]
```

But according to Microsoft Teams documentation "Reference: Manifest schema for Microsoft Teams" the "type" property doesn't exist !
see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema

BTW, import existing app in MS Teams fails !

Is it a bug or, someone know why it disappears ?

Comment: Oups... "This feature is in developer preview." nevertheless, activating developer preview in MS Teams doesn't fix.

Comment: I have tried "type:action" and uploaded manifest file worked fine. can you please upload manifest file and test once.

Comment: I do confirm that inserting line "type:"action" in command make manisfestfile import fail.

Comment: The part below is NOT ok, while removing line `"type":"action",` is OK `{
                    "id": "actionTest",
                    "title": "An action for test ",
                    "description": "An action for test",
     "type":"action",
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "I do need",
                            "title": "this parameter",
                            "description": "I do need thid parameter"
                        }
                    ]

                }`

Comment: We are working on publishing next schema version which will have all these properties. With new (probably 1.4) scheama, you should be able to upload your app with messaging extensions actions.